# css columns shrinking 100% pixel value

Tags: css, height, pixel

I have a page which is divided up into 3 divs, left center and right. I don't want to display anything in the left and right, they just frame the page.

```
    #leftDiv
{
    background-color: Gray;
    width: 10%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}

#rightDiv
{
    background-color: Gray;
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    left: 90%;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    clear:both;
}
```

The center div has a table, which allows the user to select how many rows to see. If they chose a large value then the body of the table went beyond the bottom of the left and right div.

To correct this I put the following code in

```
if ($("#leftDiv").length == 1) {
                $("#leftDiv").height($("body").height() + "px");
            }
            if ($("#rightDiv").length == 1) {
                $("#rightDiv").height($("body").height() + "px"); ;
            }
```

this works fine until the user selects a smaller value than the page size, after selecting a larger value.
Then the left and right divs get set to less than 100%.
What i need is a way to find out what 100% is in pixels and then I can compare this to the height of the body and decide which is bigger.

Any ideas?

Thanks

John

Answer (score 3):

**Use `margin: 0 auto`**

Kill your left and right columns, give your main div a width, and then center that div using an auto left and right margin.  For example:

```
#mainDiv {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: All three of the solutions have the issue, that my mainDiv / content  / center_div is not sizing to 100% of the window. Thus I have the gray background along the size and halfway up the page. I've set the min-height to 100% but it doesn't seem to matter. I'm creating a wizard which has different content on different pages.

Comment: Put the background on the `<body>` tag or some other outer div.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you creating empty elements to frame the page? How about setting the `body` background to the colour you require and:

```
#center_div {width: /* whatever */;
             margin: 0 auto; /* to center in the viewport */
             overflow: auto; /* or visible */
}
```

You could leave off the `overflow` property, and simply use `min-width` in place of `width` (I can't remember how cross-browser compatible this is) to define the 'normal' width, in such a way that the content will force the div to be larger as required to display the content.

Comment: I do wish people would stop and explain the down-votes, just occasionally. For kicks. And so that I could learn what was misleading, or wrong, in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the left and right divs don't have any contents, then there's no need for them to be separate divs: apply their formatting to your container div instead, and center your contents div using `margin: 0 auto`. Obviously, you'll need to give the container div a specified width, and a non-transparent background. Then you can let the browser take care of resizing the window as needed - there's no need for you to reinvent the wheel for that part.

CSS:

```
#container {background-color:gray;}
#content {background-color:white;width:80%;margin:0 auto;}
```

Html:

```
...
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
...your content here...
</div>
</div>
</body>
...
```

(If your page doesn't have a container div, then you can apply the background color to the body element instead, and save even more code.)